# Cannot get Ubuntu to boot besides Windows 8.1 on an HP ProBook

Tags: uefi

My HP ProBook 4540s has Window 8.1 installed, but I need Linux (Ubuntu) as well. So I installed it after making the Windows partition smaller. The system directly boots into Windows bypassing grub.

The boot mode is UEFI with CSM. The Boot Repair disk complains that the system doesn't use UEFI for booting, but legacy. Of course for starting up the Boot Repair Disk the CSM (compatibilty support module) has been used.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10252337/ shows my configuration (uploaded by Boot Repair Disk).

*Trying a Boot Repair I get the message "The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. Please change it to EFI mode. Please use Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd) which contains an EFI-compatible version of this software. ((use it from live-USB, not from DVD))*

I am already using this very Boot Repair Disk and also created a USB stick of it, but the notebook refuses to boot from it. Another USB stick with the Ubuntu 14.10 installation boots fine.

How can I get the Boot Repair Disk to work? Or is there another way of getting my system to boot into grub in order to have dual boot?

Comment: I had copied the Boot Repair Disk .iso onto the USB stick, but this leads to legacy booting. After switching off legacy booting in the computer settings, it wouldn't boot at all. Creating a EFI bootable USB stick is easy, though. Just create a FAT32 partition, make it bootable and copy all files from the .iso filesystem onto this partition. Make sure you won't leave any hidden files. 7z x /home/hj/Downloads/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso -o/mnt worked for me. Trying to re-install now.

Comment: I wrote about my installing dual-boot, but it's in German:
http://holgerjakobs.blogspot.de/2015/02/dualboot-windows-81-und-ubuntu-1410-auf.html

Comment: It looks like the wisdom of askubuntu has been concentrated into https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with dual-booting Win8 and Ubuntu, and later I found it was because of FastBoot. Here are the steps you should follow in order to be able to boot into Windows and Ubuntu.

1. Back up Windows
2. Create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive
3. Shrink your Windows partition
4. Turn off fast boot
5. Turn off secure boot
6. Install Ubuntu
7. Boot Repair
8. Fix the boot loader
9. Reboot into Ubuntu (testing)
10. Reboot into Windows (testing)

You can find a very detailed guide on how to accomplish all these steps [here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be related to Secure Boot: [Install Linux on UEFI PC with Secure Boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/)

/EDIT: All PCs delivered with Win8.1 and UEFI might have Secure Boot activated by default, but you can deactivate it in BIOS and run a legacy installation.

Comment: NEgative, WIndows 8.1 can install and run in Legacy BIOS  booting mode as well. I have one such machine that does not support EFI or UEFI and runs WIN 8.1 without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dual boot with windows without having to turn off fastboot and UEFI then you can do so by following these simple steps

You have to burn iso image to your USB using a different software and then you can install it as usual, without turning UEFI or fastboot off. 
Just follow these simple steps

1. Download Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 Disk Image.
2. Download and install wind32Diskimager
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/
3. Open the software, locate your downloaded Ubuntu Image and removable drive and click write.
4. Boot from usb and install ubuntu. (Remember to not chose the option which says install alongside windows but the option which says something else).